# How to export only two columns from database table in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am pretty noob at databases yet. 
I am trying to export two columns from table, ID and CONF_TEXT in txt file or any other format as ID, Conf_text (ex: 121,Conf text...).
[image: Database table]

Anyone done the same before?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
SELECT * FROM 'conf'
```

use

```
SELECT ID,CONF_TEXT FROM 'conf'
```

and them export

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin and fire the following query:

SELECT ID, CONF_TEXT INTO OUTFILE 'abc.txt' FROM `conf`;

Then go to your xampp/wamp/mamp folder, then go inside mysql folder then in the data folder just search for the 'abc.txt' file. (Just search for the file name in the search box once you are inside data folder of mysql, you will get your abc.txt file having the data of two columns). Similarly, to get the file in csv format, change the extension of from .txt to .csv

Hope this helps!!!